# fullpage.js with require.js IScroll not found

Tags: requirejs, fullpage.js

I´m trying to load fullpage.js with require.js. My config defines therefore a path:

```
    "fullpage":[
        "lib/jquery.fullPage.min"
    ],
```

later in main.js I require start.js which holds the business logic.

In start.js I defined the dependencies and initalized fullpage

```
define(["jquery","fullpage","nerveSlider","fluidbox"], function($,fullpage,nerveSlider,fluidbox) {
...
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['shop', 'about', 'details', 'footer'],
            sectionsColor: ['#000000', '#94c9b7', '#6e8394','#333'],
            navigation: true,
            controlArrows: true,
            fixedElements: '.logo',
            loopHorizontal: false,
            navigationPosition: 'left',
            responsiveWidth: 900,
            scrollOverflow: true
        });
```

as I´m using option 'scrollOverflow: true' fullpage.js needs scrolloverflow library: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#including-files

which I defined as deb in my main.js

```
    "scrolloverflow":[
        "lib/scrolloverflow.min"
    ],
    ...
    fullpage: {
        deps: ['scrolloverflow']
    }
```

Unfortunately I get an console error saying

```
jquery.fullPage.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? In other words how can I make method IScroll from scrolloverview available for fullpage.js?

Comment: Sounds like you are not using the latest fullpage.js version? Make sure you use the latest 2.8.4.

Comment: Alavaro, thanks for you reply! Version is 2.8.4 It seems I´m doing something wrong with require.js if I include scrolloverflow before require  `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
 <script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>` everything works fine. I think somethings wrong with the shim dependency or maybe a namespace problem.

Comment: Can you change to the unminified version and let me know in which exact line is the problem taking place ?

Comment: sure! It´s  2918 https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.js#L2918

Comment: Well, the problem is clearly that fullpage.js is being loaded before scrolloverflow.min.js. So changing the order should solve it.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, well yes but that should so the require.js magic. Or as far as I have understood with AMD modules. For others there should be the shim option. The documentation says we can force to load another lib by defining it´s deps. (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) That´s why I added scrolloverflow in fullpage deps. I think the problem is a missunderstanding on my side in shim config  ;)

Comment: I would open another question without being so specific. You don't need to mention fullpage.js at all. Just ask how to for the load of one module before another with require.js.

Comment: good idea I will. I thought it would help to reproduce the problem. thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

From [shim doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

> Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization for older, traditional "browser globals" scripts that do not use define() to declare the dependencies and set a module value.

Both `fullpage.js` and `scrolloverflow.js` are AMD modules.

You cannot use **shim** for these modules.

You define relations for module in `define` function. **fullpage.js** needs **IScroll** defined in global scope. You need a hack: Load **IScroll** and define it at global scope:

```
define(["jquery","scrolloverflow","fullpage"], function($, IScroll) {
  window.IScroll = IScroll;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, that´s what I tried at first: `define(["jquery","fullpage","scrolloverflow","nerveSlider","fluidbox"], function($,fullpage,scrolloverflow,nerveSlider,fluidbox) { ...
` but the error message stays the same :(  `Uncaught ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined`

Comment: Hi Tomasz, thanks a lot for your commitment. Your Idea is to make the IScroll global, right? Unfortunately with this it stays the same. Console says. that IScroll is undefined.`Uncaught ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined`